# How I can get email headers programmatically from MS Exchange Server in Java?

Tags: java, header, outlook, exchange-server

I can't get access to headers in email. At that moment I can get only ExtendedPropertyCollection object, but I don't know how to work with it.

```
ItemEvent item = (ItemEvent) event;
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(args.getSubscription().getService(), item.getItemId());
ExtendedPropertyCollection extendedProperties = ((ExtendedPropertyCollection) message.getExtendedProperties());
```

**UPDATE:**

The result code in Java looks like:

```
PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.MimeContent);
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(args.getSubscription().getService(), item.getItemId(), propertySet);
String emailTextWithHeaders = new String(message.getMimeContent().getContent());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that you should be able to access the InternetMessageHeader collection vai the EmailMessage class https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/InternetMessageHeader.java

The other way is to use the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS extended property eg

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x007D, MapiPropertyType.String);
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) { PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS};
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(args.getSubscription().getService(), item.getItemId(),psPropSet);
```

Cheers
Glen